# Why lowercase user name need to be in double quote while connecting Oracle?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, toad

I was trying to create user by using Toad for Mac and SQLpLus. I created user and granted permissions successfully.

If I use lowercase for the user name, I noticed that I have to specify it in double quotes while using it over TOAD. Otherwise It can not find the user. On login process It returns "ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied".

But If I create it by using SQL plus there is no need to specify with double quotes. Any idea?

Comment: Can you give the DDL command you used to create the user (and which UI you used to run that command) and an example of how you are connecting via each UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle's data dictionary is case sensitive. Oracle will abstract this case sensitivity from the user by converting all unquoted object names to upper case; however (double) quoted object names will not undergo this transformation and will be stored in the data dictionary in the case they were entered.

So:

```
CREATE USER "CAT" IDENTIFIED BY hat1;
CREATE USER "cat" IDENTIFIED BY hat2;
CREATE USER "Cat" IDENTIFIED BY hat3;
```

Will create three different users `CAT`, `cat` and `Cat`.

However:

```
CREATE USER cat IDENTIFIED BY hat1;
CREATE USER Cat IDENTIFIED BY hat1;
CREATE USER CAT IDENTIFIED BY hat1;
CREATE USER "CAT" IDENTIFIED BY hat1;
```

are all equivalent statements since the unquoted user names will be converted to upper case `CAT`.

If you want to connect to a user then you will need to make sure that the case of the user name is correct - and SQL/Plus will perform the same conversion on unquoted names.

So, given the top example, you would need to use:

```
CONNECT cat/hat1
CONNECT "CAT"/hat1
CONNECT "cat"/hat2
CONNECT "Cat"/hat3
```

*Note: the unquoted and quoted upper-case usernames are identical.*

> If I use lowercase for the user name, I noticed that I have to specify it in double quotes while using it over TOAD. Otherwise It can not find the user. On login process It returns "ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied".

I do not use Toad so I cannot comment on how it formats the connection command, but it would appear from your description that it is not wrapping the user name in double quotes so you will need to do that yourself to match the exact case stored in the database.

Answer (score 1):

By default Oracle data dictionary uses UPPER CASE for object names. Consider statement like this:

```
create table t23 (col1 number);
```

To find these details we need to

```
select * from user_tables where table_name = 'T23';
select * from user_tab_columns where table_name = 'T23' and column_name = 'COL1';
```

But if we use double quotes in the identifiers the data dictionary stores those as is:

```
create table "t42" ("col1" number);
```

Consequently this query won't find anything:

```
select * from user_tables where table_name = 'T42';
```

but this will:

```
select * from user_tab_columns where table_name = 't42' and column_name = 'col1';
```

We need to use double-quotes to reference the identifier:

```
alter table "t42" modify "col1" varchar2(10);
```

Providing we create objects with upper case identifiers or without double quotes everything is fine.

This is fine:

```
create user cat identified by cat;
```

This would also be fine (assuming you haven't already run the previous statement):

```
create user "CAT" identified by hat;
```

In either case we can connect as `conn cat/hat`

So it seems like Toad for Mac is wrapping your object in double-quotes. So if you use lower case what it executes is

```
create user "cat" identified by "hat"
```

In which case you will have to use double-quotes and keep the case correct whenever you refer to that user: `conn "cat"/hat`. `CAT` and `"cat"` are different users.

This behaviour may be configurable in TOAD - have a poke around the Preferences menu. Otherwise just be careful to always use upper-case for database objects (don't worry about passwords, they are case-sensitive in 11g and later.

Comment: The data dictionary does not use upper case for object names - Oracle will, by default, convert all unquoted object identifiers to upper case and all (double) quoted identifiers will keep their case unchanged and this will be stored in the data dictionary which is case sensitive. If you do `CREATE USER cat IDENTIFIED BY hat` and then try doing `CREATE USER "CAT" IDENTIFIED BY hat` it will fail with `ORA-01920: user name 'CAT' conflicts with another user or role name` but `CREATE USER "cat" IDENTIFIED BY hat` will work and you will have two users `CAT` and `cat` with different cases.

Comment: `select * from user_tab_columns where table_name = '"t42"' and column_name = '"col1"';` should be `select * from user_tab_columns where table_name = 't42' and column_name = 'col1';` as the data dictionary does not store the double quotes around identifiers.